# How can I solve my blank screen problem while deploying my shiny app?

Tags: r, deployment, shiny

I'm trying to deploy a shiny app, acording the following article: https://www.r-bloggers.com/deploying-desktop-apps-with-r/.

When I run my program, the Chrome initiates, but I got nothing, only a blank screen.

This is my shiny app, called runShinyApp.R:

```
library(shiny)
message('library paths:\n', paste('... ', .libPaths(), sep='', collapse='\n'))

chrome.portable = file.path(getwd(),
                            'GoogleChromePortable/App/Chrome-bin/chrome.exe')

launch.browser = function(appUrl, browser.path=chrome.portable) {
  message('Browser path: ', browser.path)
  shell(sprintf('"%s" --app=%s', browser.path, appUrl))
}

shiny::runApp('./shiny/', launch.browser=launch.browser)
```

My server file:

```
library(shiny)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # MODIFY CODE BELOW: Wrap in observeEvent() so the help text 
  # is displayed when a user clicks on the Help button.
  observeEvent(input$show_help, {
    # Display a modal dialog with bmi_help_text
    # MODIFY CODE BELOW: Uncomment code
    showModal(modalDialog(bmi_help_text))
  })
  rv_bmi <- eventReactive(input$show_bmi, {
    input$weight/(input$height^2)
  })
  output$bmi <- renderText({
    bmi <- rv_bmi()
    paste("Hi", input$name, ". Your BMI is", round(bmi, 1))
  })
}
```

My ui file:

```
library(shiny)
bmi_help_text <- ""
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel('BMI Calculator'),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput('name', 'Enter your name'),
      numericInput('height', 'Enter your height in meters', 1.5, 1, 2),
      numericInput('weight', 'Enter your weight in Kilograms', 60, 45, 120),
      actionButton("show_bmi", "Show BMI"),
      # CODE BELOW: Add an action button named "show_help"
      actionButton("show_help", "Help")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("bmi")
    )
  )
)
```

The error screen:
[image: The error screen]

Comment: As you say "deploy", I'm guessing that you mean "put my app on a server rather than running it on my desktop".  Do the server logs give you ay clues?  Does the app run as you expect on your desktop?

Comment: @Limey, what I mean is "running it on my desktop". My objective is to execute my shiny app on a computer that doesn't have R installed.

Comment: @Limey, when I put together the files "ui.R" and "server.R", I can run it (on RStudio) perfectly. When I try to run it, I can see this in my log: library paths:
... C:/Users/servo/OneDrive/Documentos/testdist/R-Portable/App/R-Portable/library

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6390
Browser path: C:/Users/servo/OneDrive/Documentos/testdist/GoogleChromePortable/App/Chrome-bin/chrome.exe
Warning: Error in shinyApp: objeto 'server' não encontrado
^C

Comment: Well, my Portugese isn't great, but that looks like "object `server` not found".  I notice you have a call to `shinyApp` in both `server.R` and `ui.R`.  That could be a problem...

Comment: @Limey, I removed the call in both, but I still have the same problem. I updated my question, pasting the image of the blank window.